# Current source should work but doesn't?

Tags: operational-amplifier, 555, current-source

I have having issues with these opamp current sources with a current source controlled 555 sawtooth generator.

I have tried all of opamp current sources and they all don't work? If I attach a current source to the simulation it works fine? But than if I try the voltage controlled current sources made using opamps, it doesn't work at all?

[roel arits on voltage controlled current sources](https://sites.google.com/site/roelarits/home/articles/current-related-topics/current-sources-1#h.p_cJuWxrrWuEXE)

[image: current sources]

Falstad circuit simulation with 555 sawtooth generator:

[image: 555 sawtooth generator]

Comment: What load do you use, and where is the other end of the load connected to? (In the falstad.com image, I find it confusing to have two nodes designated *out*.)

Comment: @greybeard , One is the output of the 555 and the other is the output where the sawtooth waveforrm is at.  You can see both current sources connect to the threshold, trigger and discharge pins.

Comment: You can't drive a current into an open output. You have to connect a load before it will be able to produce a current. (Also 200 kohms is extremely high for a sense resistor unless the desired output current is in the microamp range)

Comment: Also your op-amp is configured for positive feedback, so this will not regulate the current, it will drive the output to either maximum or minimum voltage depending on start-up conditions.

Comment: @ThePhoton  Is those circuit diagrams for a voltage op amp current source I got from a website wrong?  This is also what I was thinking previously.

Comment: @MichaelWeaser, notice that some of the diagrams have feedback to the inverting input and some have feedback to the non-inverting input of the op-amp. Since your BJT subcircuit inverts the feedback signal, you need to take feedback to the non-inverting op-amp input.

Comment: The current source cannot operate in the 5 to 10V output range of the '555 capacitor unless the (+) terminal of the op amp is at a voltage in the (15V, 10.3V) range.   Outside that range, the transistor has no proper bias.

Comment: `You can see both current sources connect to the [555's sawtooth node]` actually, I can't: voltage control input, source current output, or something else? As the current is sensed relative to +15 V, connect the control voltage source there. And show the output connected, resistor or not.

Answer (score 1):

I see at least two problems with your circuit:

1. The output of the current source (the emitter of the BJT) is not connected to anything. Therefore there is nowhere for the output current to go.
2. The op-amp is configured for positive feedback, so its output will drive to one rail or the other depending on start-up conditions. It won't produce a controlled output current. You should arrange the feedback like the 2nd-from-the-left diagram in your first image to achieve negative feedback.

Other possible issues:

- 200 kohms is a very large sense resistor value. If your goal is output currents bigger than a few microamps, you'll need to lower this resistor value.
- The feedback path in this circuit has very high gain (unless the load resistance is very high), and it may be subject to instability. The leftmost diagram in your first image is less likely to have this problem.

Comment: People seeing my falstad circuit, should understand what connects to what in the circuit?

Comment: @MichaelWeaser We will understand that the things are connected that are shown as connected in the diagram. We can't read your mind to guess that there are connections made that aren't shown in the diagram (and also the simulator won't just guess either --- it will simulate the circuit based on the connections you actually draw)

Comment: I'll just fix the diagram to show what connects to what.

Comment: @MichaelWeaser, I'm not going to play 20 questions with you and try to change my answer every time you change the question.

Comment: I only fixed the diagram, because I understood where you are going at with the circuit.  I know that a person is gonna answer based on what they see in the post. I feel stupid for not just posting the diagram with all the correct connection in the 1st place etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your current source PNP transistor needs to be biased properly in the Falstad simulation. Set the reference voltage to the opamp higher than **max. voltage of the capacitor + VCESAT of the PNP**

Right now, the reference voltage of 1V is too low.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, the first (left) circuit should work, and it probably does. You've just misinterpreted what voltage needs to be at \$V_{IN}\$ to set the current through \$R_{SET}\$.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqBZCQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In that circuit the op-amp is there to ensure \$V_E = V_{IN}\$. That's all it does. Your goal is to apply a voltage *across* \$R_{SET}\$, which will determine the current through it, which will become \$I_{OUT}\$.

The voltage \$V_{RSET}\$ across \$R_{SET}\$ is:

$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{RSET} &= V_{CC} - V_E \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Since \$V_E = V_{IN}\$, this becomes:

$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{RSET} &= V_{CC} - V_{IN} \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Using Ohm's law, we have current \$I_{OUT}\$:

$$
\begin{aligned}
I_{OUT} &= \frac{V_{RSET}}{R_{SET}} \\ \\
&= \frac{V_{CC} - V_{IN}}{R_{SET}} \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

You must also ensure that potential \$V_C\$ at node C is able to rise in potential to well above the minimum that you ever expect to find at the 555's trigger and threshold inputs. That will be about \$\frac{2}{3}V_{CC}\$. Just to be safe, let's say that the voltage across \$R_{SET}\$ must never be more than 1V, meaning or, \$V_E > V_{CC} - 1V\$. In other words, \$V_{IN} > 14V\$ in your Falstad circuit.

As you have it, \$V_{IN} = +1V\$ which completely violates that requirement.

As a practical example, assuming \$V_{CC}=+15V\$, first figure out what maximum current you need. Let's say \$I_{OUT(MAX)} = 1mA\$. Then you must find what value of \$R_{SET}\$ will pass 1mA with 1V across it:

$$
\begin{aligned}
R_{SET} &= \frac{V_{RSET}}{I_{OUT(MAX)}} \\ \\
&= \frac{1V}{1mA} = 1k\Omega \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Now you can use the equation from before to find what output current \$I_{OUT}\$ corresponds to what input potential \$V_{IN}\$:

$$
\begin{aligned}
I_{OUT} &= \frac{V_{CC} - V_{IN}}{R_{SET}} \\ \\
&= \frac{15V - V_{IN}}{1k\Omega} \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

In this example, extremes of \$V_{IN}=+15V\$ and \$V_{IN}=+14V\$ correspond to \$I_{OUT}=0\$ and \$I_{OUT}=1mA\$ respectively, and the relationship is nice and linear between them.

The last problem you might encounter, is if your op-amp is unable to produce an output close to its positive supply, or its input voltage range does not include that positive supply potential. This will be the case for the LM358, for example. You will require a rail-to-rail op-amp to implement this design.

Comment: But there is a issue, I used the current source option in falstad to figure out what current to get a certain frequency output , than using the op amp circuit , I figured out how to get the same current, hooked it up and it still doesn't work? But also the current required to get a frequency output I just randomly picked is also very low. 200 uA gives an output of a 100 hz sawtooth waveform.

Comment: @MichaelWeaser 200µA through a capacitance of 200nF would cause a voltage increase across the cap of 1000V/s, a slope which is *about* right for a 100Hz sawtootth, not accounting for other factors. What's the issue, exactly?

Comment: It seems like the issue has to do with what someone posted above with the voltage going into the op amp which is the reference voltage?

Comment: @MichaelWeaser your Falstad circuit approach is fine, it's just you need +14V at the non-inverting input, and a much smaller emitter resistor, like 10k or 1k. Just try that first.